# Enable XSLT in PHP5

Tags: php, xslt

I am developing an application with php where I need to use XML files and transform them by using a XSL style sheet. I am using PHP5 and Linux and the problem is I dont know how to enable the xslt module.

Comment: SOLUTION: I finally got it by running:

    sudo apt-get install php5-xsl

and then restarting the server

Comment: Please add that as an answer below and accept it. This will then mark your question as solved. This is how the site works, so please do so and help us improving ;)

Answer (score 1):

> SOLUTION: I finally got it by running: sudo apt-get install php5-xsl and then restarting the server